# oauth2.0 azure AD APIM where to store the token

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I have a OAuth2.0 enabled in my APIM and i am going to generate token from Azure AD with the client ID and Secret from the KeyValut?

I need to know where to store this token in the APIM or Azure. Because I am assuming, there could be many requests from the client API to our API and I want a way to store the Client Credentials flow Bearer token generated. how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the token in APIM. See this example: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Backend%20OAuth2%20Authentication%20With%20Cache.policy.xml

Comment: Thank you, will this work for many client APIs calling our API? Also, where these token for say 10 clients are stored? I am taking 10 as example here, but as many different client requests, that many tokens needed to be stored. Where are these stored in APIM for a single API? Can we not store these in KeyVault?

Comment: If you store it in KeyVault then each request will have to make a call to KeyVault to obtain the token, that would increase latency. Storing it in APIMs cache however would make it available for any request very quickly.